# Using Hibernate's MatchMode for a Date object

Tags: hibernate

I have a Date object for a date "26/12/2007" which I want to compare with my date in my MySQL database "26/12/2007 12:00:00". Like if I send a date "26/12/2007" it should retrieve values against the date in MySQL database.

It works if I remove this "12:00:00", but if I add "12:00:00"- it gives no results.

I am using Hibernate Criteria like

```java
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("dateinsql", date));
```

I tried using

```java
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("dateinsql", date,MatchMode.AnyWhere));
```

but it only works for *String* not *Date*.

Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to reformat your date variable's pattern, i.e., get its string format according to a specified date pattern and and then convert it back to date object.`"dd MMM yyyy"` is the format that works for hibernate.

try this:-

```
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(your_input_date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // this is needed to if you want to deal with 12 hrs difference.

    SimpleDateFormat sdf    =   new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    Date formattedDate = sdf.parse(org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateFormatUtils.format(calendar.getTime(),"dd MMM yyyy"));
```

Using this formatted date,

`criteria.add(Restrictions.like("dateinsql", formattedDate ));`

should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but no luck,  the formatteddate i am getting with your code is : Mon Jul 04 00:00:00 EDT 2011  and in mySQL is :2011-07-04 12:31:39  , so i don't think it could match , any suggestion

Comment: If you require to search within the 24 hrs range then use less than and greater than restrictions, i.e., `criteria.add(Restrictions.ge ("dateinsql",formattedDate)).add(Restrictions.lt("dateinsql",currentDate));`where `currentDate=sdf.parse(DateFormatUtils.format(your_input_date,"dd MMM yyyy"));` This would give you a range of 24 hrs for ,say, jul 4 00:00 till july 5 00:00